# Ruby on Rails 2 - Confusion over belongs_to, has_one, has_many etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-2

I have two objects, `Vpn` and `Organisation`

**organisation.rb**

```
has_many :vpns, :foreign_key => "managed_by"
```

**vpn.rb**

```
belongs_to :managed_by, :class_name => "Organisation", :foreign_key => "managed_by"
```

So, the `vpns` table has a `managed_by` column which is effectively an organisation id but I don't want to name it `organisation_id` to avoid confusion.

With this associated, in my list view I can do

```
<%= vpn.managed_by.nil? ? '' : vpn.managed_by.name %>
```

To get the name of the organisation the `managed_by` field relates to but if I try and update the attributes I get `ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in VpnController#update`, so for some reason an object is expected rather than the string, the params sent in the request are as expected:

```
{"id"=>"1",
 "authenticity_token"=>"RWu39MOqDiu8vbuAfPzyJXAP1CKIaxIFoUjwLl2pemc=",
 "commit"=>"Save",
 "vpn"=>{"id"=>"1",
 "managed_by"=>"999"}}
```

To avoid leaving anything out, the `managed_by` in my form is presented as a `select` menu using `collection_select`:

```
<%= collection_select 'vpn', 'managed_by', @organisations, :id, :name, {:selected_value => @vpn.managed_by} %>
```

Where `@organisations` is just an active record result containing all organisations.

If I change the `belongs_to` in `vpn.rb` to

```
belongs_to :organisation, :class_name => "Organisation", :foreign_key => "managed_by"
```

The update works fine but then on the list view I get an error trying to retrieve the name of the organisation:

```
undefined method `name' for 999:Fixnum
```

Comment: thanks, but have you got an example on how I should properly fix this association?

Comment: I made my comment an answer, with an example. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're doing is very confusing: you have two things (a belongs-to association and a foreign key) that are both called `managed_by`. I don't think there is anything you can do to make Rails deal with that. If you want to keep the `managed_by` column in your database, you should think of another name for your association.

I suggest you use:

```
belongs_to :organisation, :class_name => "Organisation", :foreign_key => "managed_by"
```

like you already tried. To fix the error in your view, you have to use this:

```
<%= vpn.organisation.nil? ? '' : vpn.organisation.name %>
```

When using `vpn.managed_by` Rails looks at the foreign key, which is an integer, not an `Organisation` object.

Comment: Did you put `:foreign_key => "managed_by"` in the `belongs_to` call?

Comment: great, that fixed it - genuinely didn't know that the active record relations were named, I always assumed it was just the name of the table and pluralised if it was a one to many etc.